# Fullcalendar Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token em descrição quando pulo linha

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

Estou usando como base este calendário
https://github.com/GabrielpBiu/calendario-de-eventos-php-fullcalendar-mysql
Na descrição existe um textarea. Quando pulo linha e salvo no banco, não consegue carregar o calendário por causa do erro
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No banco está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como faço par acorrigir?

Comment: Isso pode estar acontecendo por N motivos, versão do seu banco, versão do seu php ou configuração do seu servidor. Eu trabalho em um server que não aceita quebra de linhas, pois o php interpreta a quebra como uma nova linha, gerando o mesmo erro que você tem. Resolvi o problema usando uma duas funções uma para tratar a entrada do texto e a outro para tratar a saída, vou postar abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira trata a quebra de linha que sai do seu textarea para salvar no banco, se você quiser pode colocar um `<br>` no str_replace.

```
public function trataQuebra($texto){
    $processa_texto = preg_replace("/\r?\n/","", $texto);
    $processa_texto = str_replace('"', '', $processa_texto);
    $processa_texto = str_replace("'", "", $processa_texto);
    return trim($processa_texto);
}
```